# Draw arrow in a mind map

Tags: tikz-arrows

I used the PGF manual to help me draw a figure like the image below.
[image: Mind map drawn with PGF]

But I'd like to add some arrows to indicate the flow of the events, like this image (I made it with Paint)

[image: Mind map drawn with Paint]

I don't know how to that, because it's not a simple arrow.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}     
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,indentfirst,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,newlfont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[algosection,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, scale=1.1]
        \node (n1) at (3,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue!65,text=white] {$\stackrel{4.}{\stackrel{Dual}{\textrm{\scriptsize \em Adjustment}}}$};
        \node (n2) at (0,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{1.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 1}{\textrm{\scriptsize times = 1}}}$};
        \node (n3) at (0,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{2.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 1}{\textrm{\scriptsize times = 2}}}$};
        \node (n4) at (0,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{3.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 2}{}}$};
        \node (n5) at (3,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,red,text=white] {$\stackrel{5.}{LB}$};
        \node (n6) at (5,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!70!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{6.}{\textrm{\scriptsize Feasibility}}$};
        \node (n7) at (7,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!80!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{7.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 1}}}$};
        \node (n8) at (10,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!80!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{8.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 2}}}$};
        \node (n9) at (11.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,red,text=white] {$\stackrel{11.}{UB}$};
        \node (n10) at (5.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=2.3cm,fill,draw,thick,orange!60!gray,text=white] {$\stackrel{9.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Ascent}}}$};
        \node (n11) at (8.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,orange!60!gray,text=white] {$\stackrel{10.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 2}}}$};

        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n2);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n3);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n4);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (red)] (n5);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (gray!70!green)] (n6);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (gray!80!green)] (n7);
        \path (n6) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!70!green) to (gray!80!green)] (n7);
        \path (n7) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!80!green) to (gray!80!green)] (n8);
        \path (n8) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!80!green) to (red)] (n9);
        \path (n11) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!60!gray) to (orange!60!gray)] (n10);
        \path (n11) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!60!gray) to (red)] (n9);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Comment: That's pretty difficult to pull off. You might add it manually just like you did it in paint.

Comment: @percusse you, specially *you*, saying this? ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I meant what you wrote placing manually :) But the colors would start getting funky if you want to change the size of the arrow etc. ;)

Comment: @percusse I know, I was just kidding :-). I will delete my previous comment and this one shortly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah come on. We can stretch a little :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One idea: since changing individual connection bars is not easy, you can draw the arrow in the background (I used the `backgrounds` library and a customized `Stealth` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}     
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,indentfirst,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,newlfont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[algosection,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, scale=1.1]
        \node (n1) at (3,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue!65,text=white] {$\stackrel{4.}{\stackrel{Dual}{\textrm{\scriptsize \em Adjustment}}}$};
        \node (n2) at (0,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{1.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 1}{\textrm{\scriptsize times = 1}}}$};
        \node (n3) at (0,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{2.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 1}{\textrm{\scriptsize times = 2}}}$};
        \node (n4) at (0,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,blue,text=white] {$\stackrel{3.}{\stackrel{Dual\ Ascent\ 2}{}}$};
        \node (n5) at (3,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,red,text=white] {$\stackrel{5.}{LB}$};
        \node (n6) at (5,-2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!70!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{6.}{\textrm{\scriptsize Feasibility}}$};
        \node (n7) at (7,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!80!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{7.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 1}}}$};
        \node (n8) at (10,0) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,gray!80!green,text=white] {$\stackrel{8.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 2}}}$};
        \node (n9) at (11.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,red,text=white] {$\stackrel{11.}{UB}$};
        \node (n10) at (5.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=2.3cm,fill,draw,thick,orange!60!gray,text=white] {$\stackrel{9.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Ascent}}}$};
        \node (n11) at (8.5,2.5) [circle,minimum size=1cm,fill,draw,thick,orange!60!gray,text=white] {$\stackrel{10.}{\stackrel{Primal}{\textrm{\scriptsize Adjustment\ 2}}}$};

        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n2);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n3);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (blue)] (n4);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (red)] (n5);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (gray!70!green)] (n6);
        \path (n1) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!65) to (gray!80!green)] (n7);
        \path (n6) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!70!green) to (gray!80!green)] (n7);
        \path (n7) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!80!green) to (gray!80!green)] (n8);
        \path (n8) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (gray!80!green) to (red)] (n9);
        \path (n11) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!60!gray) to (orange!60!gray)] (n10);
        \path (n11) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (orange!60!gray) to (red)] (n9);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}    
    \draw 
      [concept connection,->,blue!70,shorten >= -0.15pt,-{Stealth[angle=70:1pt 6]}] 
      (n2) to (n1);
    \draw 
      [concept connection,->,orange!60!gray!90!red,shorten >= -0.15pt,-{Stealth[angle=70:1pt 6]}] 
      (n9) to (n11);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

On a side note, be careful with some of the packages loaded: `subfigure` and `epsfig` are obsolote and shouldn't be used anymore; they've been superseeded by `subfig` or `subcaption`, the former, and by `graphicx`, the latter. Also, you are loading `graphicx` twice and `graphics`; it's enough to load `graphicx` (once). More dangerous: you are loading `amsmath` twice: once with `centertags` options and then with no options; this can produce clashes. On modern systems, there's no need to explicitly specify the driver for `hyperref`, so instead of

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
```

use

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Perfect @Gonzalo Medina !!! that was a great idea. Thank you very much

Comment: That looks good. It wouldn't be bad as a new feature to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to point out that loading some of those packages is Bad?

Comment: @cfr True. I've added a remark about some of the packages. I am not sure about `newlfont`. Do you have any suggestions about this package? Thanks.

Comment: (+1) I don't know about `newlfont`. Is it just obsolete? It seems to exist to support deprecated syntax. So I'd use it only if I couldn't easily update a document's syntax, I think, or if I really had to use a package which depended on stuff like `\newmathalphabet`. (I've never seen this command before - I guess it is 2.09?) `amsmath` is also loaded with different options, by the way.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I saw that it's from Frank and it seems to offer support for old syntax. No idea, however, what to suggest to the OP. Thanks for the heads up about `amsmath` :-)